# How to setup on_message with sqlite3 in discord.py?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Hi I created the following event. It takes input one time after that it stores the guild id , channel id and role id in sqlite db . After that when someone in that particular guild mentions minimum 3 users in a particular channel , the bot gives them  new role.

```
class ScrimsCog(commands.Cog, name='Scrims-Commands') :

        def __init__(self,bot):
            self.bot = bot
        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_message(self, message):
            if message.guild:
                db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(
                    f"SELECT * FROM main WHERE guild_id = ?", (message.guild.id, ))
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                if result:
                    channel = self.bot.get_channel(result[2])
                    role = message.guild.get_role(result[1])
                    if role:
                        if message.channel == channel:
                            if len(message.mentions) >= 3:
                                await message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
                            user = message.author
                            await user.add_roles(role)
            await self.bot.process_commands(message)
            

        
        
        @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
        async def scrimsmod(self,ctx):
            await ctx.send('Available Setup Commands: \nscrimsmod channel <#channel>\nscrimsmod role  <message>')
        @scrimsmod.command()
        async def channel(self, ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
            if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
                result =  cursor.fetchone()
                if result is None:
                    sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES(?,?)")
                    val = (ctx.guild.id, channel.id)
                    await ctx.send(f" Default Registration Channel has been set to {channel.mention}")
                elif result is not None:
                    sql = ("UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
                    val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default Registration Channel has been updated to {channel.mention}")
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
                db.close()

        @scrimsmod.command()
        async def role(self, ctx,role: discord.Role):
            if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT role FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
                result =  cursor.fetchone()
                if result is None:
                    sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, role) VALUES(?,?)")
                    val = (ctx.guild.id, role.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default role to give on correct registration have been set to `{role}`")
                elif result is not None:
                    sql = ("UPDATE main SET role = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
                    val = (role.id, ctx.guild.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"Default role to give on correct registration have been updated to  `{role}`")
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
```

Well, I believe the code is fine it doesn't throw any error . The issue is that it perfectly take input without any error but doesn't store it into db.

[image]

I believe the problem is with my db,
code -

```
db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite',timeout=10)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main(
            guild_id INTEGER,
            role INTEGER,
            channel_id INTEGER
        )
    ''')
```

I believe the problem is here , I should take TEXT in place INTEGER but I am not sure. Answer me with What do you I am doing wrong and how should I fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I answered your last question with assuming that role and channel is `TEXT` type in the table and that answer should've solve your problem. If you change them, it will work fine and also it will be more efficient if you define the database variable and cursor on top of the `on_message` event just for once. So you don't have do connect to the database everytime.

Comment: Hi I have changed role , channel and guild id to text type but it is still not recording any data in db. Should I switch to some other db? @Nurqm

Comment: Try another database and try the code that I wrote in your last question.